# How to generate sequence of numbers in Tcl

Tags: list, numbers, tcl, generator, sequence

I'm looking for a way to generate a list of numbers, according to input `from`, `to` and `step` parameters.

Using `incr` is no good as I would like to support also `float` and `double` numbers.

For example, in case `from=-0.3`, `to=0.25` and `step=0.1`, I would like to generate the list `-0.3 -0.2 -0.1 0 0.1 0.2`. I'm having troubles with the formatting and rounding.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [classic problem in computing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Seriously.

What you need to do is to use integer iteration anyway and then scale by the step size. That minimises the errors. You also need to use `format` carefully.

```
set from -0.3
set to 0.25
set step 0.1
for {set i 0} true {incr i} {
    set x [expr {$i*$step + $from}]
    if {$x > $to} break
    set printable [format "%.1f" $x]
    puts "$i => $printable"
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `step` is positive; the sense of the test would need to change if `step` was negative.

Comment: Shouldn't I derive the decimal point location according to step resolution?

Comment: Strictly yes, but it's often easiest to just hard-code it. (`set decimalPlaces 1; format %.*f $decimalPlaces $x`)

Answer (score 1):

If you can remove the string prefixes yourself:

```
proc genNums {{from 0} {to 1} {step .1} {prec 1}} {
    if {$step < 0} {
        set op ::tcl::mathop::>
    } else {
        set op ::tcl::mathop::<
    }
    for {set n $from} {[$op $n $to]} {set n [expr {$n + $step}]} {
        lappend res [format %.*f $prec $n]
    }
    return $res 
}

% genNums -0.3 0.25 0.1
# => -0.3 -0.2 -0.1 0.0 0.1 0.2
% genNums -0.3 0.25 0.1 2
# => -0.30 -0.20 -0.10 0.00 0.10 0.20
```

But if you want, you can set it up so that you can pass the string to the command:

```
proc genNums args {
    array set params {from 0 to 1 step .1 prec 1}
    array set params [split [string map {= { }} $args]]
    if {$params(step) < 0} {
        set op ::tcl::mathop::>
    } else {
        set op ::tcl::mathop::<
    }
    for {set n $params(from)} {[$op $n $params(to)]} {set n [expr {$n + $params(step)}]} {
        lappend res [format %.*f $params(prec) $n]
    }
    return $res 
}

genNums from=-0.3 to=0.25 step=0.1
# => -0.3 -0.2 -0.1 0.0 0.1 0.2
% genNums from=-0.3 to=0.25 step=0.1 prec=2
# => -0.30 -0.20 -0.10 0.00 0.10 0.20
```

Documentation:
[+ (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[< (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Mathematical operators as Tcl commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm)

Comment: This function doesn't do the job, for example, using `from=-0.35` `to=0.75` and `step=0.1`. It yields `-0.3 -0.2 -0.1 -0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7`

Comment: @HardwareEng.: what sequence were you expecting? Note that this is with a single decimal: setting the format to `%.2f` might be better.

Comment: @peter, maybe add a `scale=2` argument that you can use in your format command.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about the following solution:

```
proc ::General::Range {Start Stop {Step 1}} {
    if {$Step eq 0} {return Error-'ZeroStep'}
    if {$Start eq $Stop} {return $Start}
    set Range {}
    if {![string in integer $Step]} {
        # Double
        regexp {^\d+\.(\d+)$} $Step FullMatch ToFormat
        while {$Start <= $Stop} {
            lappend Range [string trimright $Start 0]
            set Start [format "%.${ToFormat}f" [expr {$Start + $Step}]]
        }
    } else {
        # Integer
        while {[expr {$Stop > 0 ? [expr {$Start <= $Stop}] : [expr {$Start >= $Stop}]}]} {lappend Range $Start; incr Start $Step}
    }
    return $Range
}
```

Comment: If you want to compare with 0, use `==`; 0.0 isn't `eq` to 0. There is no `string in` command, you probably mean `string is`. Non-integer steps can't be negative. `string trimright $Start 0` means that you will get numbers that end in a decimal point. Getting the formatting precision from the step value will result in some weird formattings. You can't necessarily decide from the value of `Stop` whether the count is upwards or downwards.

Comment: Also, you're overusing `expr` to the point where it is making your code harder to read. There's no actual benefit from doing so.

Comment: @PeterLewerin: Thanks for your insights!

Comment: @DonalFellows: Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Tcl's coroutines to generate the next value in the range on-demand

```
% proc range {from to step} {
    yield
    set value $from
    while {$value <= $to} {
        yield $value
        set value [expr {$value + $step}]
    }
}
% coroutine generator range -0.35 0.25 0.1
% puts [generator]
-0.35
% puts [generator]
-0.24999999999999997
% puts [generator]
-0.14999999999999997
% puts [generator]
-0.04999999999999996
% puts [generator]
0.050000000000000044
% puts [generator]
0.15000000000000005
% puts [generator]

% puts [generator]
invalid command name "generator"
```

As Donal was saying, here we see the accumulating floating point errors. Applying his method:

```
proc range {from to step} {
    yield
    set i 0
    while 1 {
        set value [expr {$from + $i * $step}]
        yield $value
        if {$value > $to} break
        incr i
    }
}
```

we get the sequence

```
-0.35
-0.24999999999999997
-0.14999999999999997
-0.04999999999999993
0.050000000000000044
0.15000000000000002
0.2500000000000001
```